# Shock when Installing Fluorescent Bulb 50VAC between frame and GLASS of Lamp - New Ballast Installed

Tags: lighting, safety, fluorescent, ballast

I have a ballast that we are replacing in a church. There are approximately 12 dual lamp T12 Fixtures in parallel drops. The fixtures are all in line -- but L1, Neutral and Ground are parallel drops.

After 40 years some ballasts have failed - they are 4-wire magnetic type units. We have purchased 5 wire electronic ballasts to replace some. Upon replacing the first ballast, a GE magnetic ballast, with a Philips QuickPro 60 Electronic Ballast I managed to get a shock installing the lamp. I measured 50 VAC between the *FRAME of the Fixture* (my ground wire is attached to the frame), and the **LAMP GLASS ITSELF** - note the GLASS which is what I was touching when I got shocked - I was touching the middle of the lamp 6 feet in so I know I was not mistaken in what I touched.

I know I wired the new Ballast Correctly.

I have attached a picture showing the new Ballast wiring at the TOP of the image and the original magnetic ballast at the bottom of the picture.

My Question is two fold:

Since I have installed an electronic ballast and the other units in parallel have magnetic ballasts could this be causing an issue ?

What could be the problem that I am measuring this 50VAC between the glass and the frame of the fixture?
[image: Example of one Fixture NEW Ballast To Old Ballast Bottom - there are 12 fixtures of the old ballast style in a row - parallel drop]

My examples of wiring are correct and I did find the culprit - I will post my answer.

Comment: Ate you sure you got shocked? 50v is pretty harmless.  The telephone system uses 90V to ring

Comment: @Kris oh I' am pretty sure I got shocked - I would almost do it again just to be sure (I am not stupid - although it might be contested somewhere down the line) - but I will leave that to someone who is electric shock qualified :-) . For me I then used my meter - 50VAC between frame and Glass Tube, the other fixtures with the Old Magnetic Ballast 1.7VAC ~ 2.5VAC - no shock when I touch frame and bulb. POTS uses 48VAC - and yes you can get shocked form that too. I have done enough ballast changes and lamp work to know this is not correct - I just do not know why.

Comment: Do the fixtures have shunting or non-shunting lampholders?

Comment: @Harper the tombstones are just tombstones with wire connectors - 1 for black hot and one for neutral white. I am thinking maybe I need to pull that assembly off and see if someone has a wire attached that I can not see. As I said the fixtures are butted up against each other in a long line. It may be someone did something sneaky on me.

Comment: Your "before" diagram looks like nothing I've ever seen! So I suspect *actually* L1 and N went to those tombstones, and another wire went from tombstone to ballast, and you presumed that was a splice (shunting) and it wasn't... and that matters.  And maybe you made that same presumption on the other end. Suffice it to say, there must be more going on here.  Looking for more wires is a great idea, I for one suspect one between the right-side tombstones.  I doubt anyone did anything *sneaky* but there's quite a variety of ways to connect ballasts.

Comment: By the way, are these fixtures in a location where it's easy to change the tubes, or hard?  If hard, you may want to switch to programmed start ballasts... the way they price ballasts (overpricing instant-start IMO), programmed-start isn't that much more.  Programmed start preheats the tube and starts it in optimum conditions, giving vastly longer tube life.

Comment: @Harper yes on the left hand side L1, N go to wire splice, Mains L1,N and also to the Tombstones on the left end as pictured are in that same splice - 3 wires - wire nutted together. The old ballast had a wiring diagram on it and showed the wiring exactly as it was wired and I drew it just like I found the wiring.

Comment: I don't believe you. Glass is one of *the* best insulators. What you probably did was have the two pins on one end complete part of the circuit and you got a *touched the other end of a florescent bulb while it was on (!) and I was changing it type zap (~50v)* and you got zapped by (an incorrectly wired thing) touching the frame or something grounded. I don't know what the problem was, but I know what you did wrong... Not that I turn them off either; just saying.

Comment: @Mazura I can see you don't understand electricity. 1: a SINGLE PIN 8 foot fluorescent light grabbed at the middle has no possibility of contacting either end with the hand! 2: GLASS is a DIELECTRIC . A Fluorescent bulb works from High Voltage, the thin glass material will allow you to be the conductor on the other end of the glass! If you have a ballast that is not grounded to the frame you can have this occurrence. A poor connection in the tombstone can also cause this.

Comment: @Mazura Yeah, Tesla did a lot of really fun stuff with wireless electric fields and making fluorescent tubes light up that he's holding in his hand with no wires connected at all.  Well, not fluorescent tubes exactly, but things so similar that a fluorescent tube would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scratching my head - I decided to pull the tombstones out and inspect the wiring to make sure there was no sneaky connections and also nothing out of the ordinary. The older ballasts (original diagram are Magnetic Ballasts with PCB) the new ballast are electronic. I contacted the manufacturer and they suggested to verify my grounds for the ballast assembly. Since I had several that were fine and all inline - I verified ground from good unit to ground on unit that I was shocked with. Grounds were good.

So upon pulling the tombstones out and checking the wiring - I tugged on each of the wires, one of the wires just slid out of the connection. While it was inserted in the tombstone connection just fine; it just kind of slid out as if the spring clamp had not locked it in. I removed the wire and installed a new wire into the tombstone making sure it clamped down on the wire. 
After I had done this there was no longer an issue. I assume the wire was close enough to conduct but far enough away to cause the issue.

I do not understand that engineering wise - but maybe it has something to do with RF, High Voltage and an Air gap.

Comment: So, a break in a conductor on a properly grounded balast can present a shock hazard through the lamp's glass?

Comment: @Mazura -- it was probably a capacitive "zing" from wire to Ken with the lamp glass in the middle -- as thus, it was impedance limited to not pose a major shock hazard, but still could give you a good nip.

Comment: @Mazura I physically measured the voltage between glass of the bulb (8 feet bulb) and the fixture I had 50VAC. After fixing the wire that reading went down to just about 1 VAC. No shock. I never experienced this before and I have changed plenty of ballasts and bulbs. I am not sure of the reason this happened but electronic ballasts operate in the Khz range and so I suspect the HV and the RF along with the 'loose connection -AirGap' of the wire to the lamp pin allowed this to occur. I searched briefly to try to understand it; all I had found so far was a spark gap transmitter.

Comment: Tubes interact with the grounded metal fixture.  Some types of ballasts (i.e. Instant) rely on this capacitive coupling  to strike the lamp, so you can get a big surprise if you use that ballast type for back illumination in a lit sign where there's only plastic on either side of the tubes.